# How to Single Signon authentication for wordpress to drupal?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, drupal

Once user logged in wordpress drupal site also should automatically loggedin. if user not available in drupal site it should insert and login into drupal. I have tried to set cookies to drupal site. but i cant resolve it. please check with my below code.

```
function drupal_authentication() {   


    $user_login = $_REQUEST["username"];
    $user_pass = $_REQUEST["password"];

    $login_url = 'http://xxxx.com/drup/user/login';

    // Preparing postdata for wordpress login
    $data = "name=".$user_login."&pass=".$user_pass."&form_id=user_login&sso=1" ;

    $cookie_file= rand().'.txt';

    $http_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0";

    // Intialize cURL
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Url to use
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    // Set the cookies for the login in a cookie file.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file );
    // Set SSL to false
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    // User agent
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $http_agent );
    // Maximum time cURL will wait for get response. in seconds
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
    // Return or echo the execution
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    // Set Http referer.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $login_url );
    // Post fields to the login url
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    // Save the return in a variable
    $content = curl_exec ($ch);  
    /*
    ** if you need to visit another url, you can do it here.
    ** curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'a new url address or a file download url' );
    ** $content = curl_exec ($ch);
    */
    // Close the cURL.
    curl_close( $ch );  
    // You can echo or return the page data here.
    $cookie_path = 'xxxxx.com';
    $f = fopen ($cookie_file, 'ro');

    $name_array = array();

    while (!feof ($f))
    { 
    $line = fgets ($f);
    $parts = explode ("\t", $line);
    $name = $parts[5];
    $value = trim ($parts[6]);

    if (!in_array($name, $name_array)){
    setcookie ($name, str_replace('%7C','|',$value), 0, '/',$cookie_path);
    $name_array[] = $name;
    }
    }

    unlink ($cookie_file);

}

add_action('wp_login', 'drupal_authentication');
```